# Which is the best approach for creating custom tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on application that is more likely a `tabBarController` application. But I can not use the `tabBarController` because I need a custom `tab` handler at the bottom also I need custom space between items. So I am creating custom `tabBarController`.

I would like to know the best approach. Currently my approach is this in way (using `storyboard` and `iOS6`) :- I took an `UIToolbar` on `ViewController` which will act as a bottom `tab` bar(CustomTabBarViewController). I took `ContainerViews` for each tab. When user selects an item on `toolbar`, I will show that `containerView`.

Please tell me if i am going wrong or guide the best way. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

You're doing it very very wrong. Do not create a custom view hierarchy when you can just use the default one.

What you want to do is to create a subclass of `UITabBarController` and also create a .xib file that will contain your custom tab bar - simply an image and an arbitrary amount of UIButtons (I suppose 5).

[image]

Set tags for all of them, just 1-5 tags, you could possibly do it with a custom `UIView` subclass, but that would be redundant in this scenario, so it'll be just fetching controls with tags.

Create a subclass of the `UITabBarController`. You'll need to have references to all those buttons and also a property to see which button was pressed last, so you could update the UI appropriately. Also assign different images or titles for different control states, I'm using default and selected in this case.

MYBaseTabBarController.h

```
@interface MYBaseTabBarController : UITabBarController
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *btn1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *btn2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *btn3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *btn4;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *btn5;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *lastSender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *tabBarView;

@end
```

MYBaseTabBarController.m

First of all, create the view controllers (which are all `UINavigationController` subclasses in this case) and assign them to your `UITabBarController`'s subclass as the `viewControllers` property.

```
- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    [self setup];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)setup {
  NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray array];

  MYViewController1 *viewController1 = [[MYStoryboardManager storyboard1] instantiateInitialViewController];
  viewController1.title = @"1";
  [viewControllers addObject:viewController1];

  MYViewController2 *viewController2 = [[MYStoryboardManager storyboard2] instantiateInitialViewController];
  viewController2.title = @"2";
  [viewControllers addObject:viewController2];

  UIViewController *blankController = [UIViewController new]; // Center button, performs an action instead of leading to a controller
  [viewControllers addObject:blankController];

  MYViewController3 *viewController3 = [[MYStoryboardManager storyboard3] instantiateInitialViewController];
  viewController3.title = @"3";
  [viewControllers addObject:viewController3];

  MYViewController3 *viewController4 = [[MYStoryboardManager storyboard4] instantiateInitialViewController];
  viewController4.title = @"4";
  [viewControllers addObject:viewController4];

  self.viewControllers = viewControllers;
}
```

Next grab the buttons you've created previously and assign actions to them in the `-viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  _tabbarView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTabBar" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject]; // "MyTabBar" is the name of the .xib file
  _tabbarView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                 self.view.frame.size.height - _tabbarView.frame.size.height,
                                 _tabbarView.frame.size.width,
                                 _tabbarView.frame.size.height); // make it overlay your actual tab bar
  [self.view addSubview:_tabbarView];

  _btn1 = (UIButton *)[_tabbarView viewWithTag:1];
  [_btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(processBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  _btn2 = (UIButton *)[_tabbarView viewWithTag:2];
  [_btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(processBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  _btn3 = (UIButton *)[_tabbarView viewWithTag:3];
  [_btn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(processBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  _btn4 = (UIButton *)[_tabbarView viewWithTag:4];
  [_btn4 addTarget:self action:@selector(processBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  _btn5 = (UIButton *)[_tabbarView viewWithTag:5];
  [_btn5 addTarget:self action:@selector(processBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  _lastSender = _btn1;
  [self setSelectedViewController:self.viewControllers[0]]; // make first controller selected
}
```

Add the processing method:

```
- (void)processBtn:(UIButton *)sender {
  _lastSender = sender;
  [self setSelectedViewController:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:sender.tag - 1]];
}
```

And finally override the `-setSelectedViewController:` method:

```
- (void)setSelectedViewController:(UIViewController *)selectedViewController {
  if (_lastSender != _btn3) { // check if it's not the action button
    for (UIButton *btn in [_tabbarView subviews]) {
      if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        if (btn == _lastSender) {
          btn.selected = YES;
        }
        else {
          btn.selected = NO;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if ([self.viewControllers indexOfObject:selectedViewController] == 2) {
    MYActionController *viewController = [[MYStoryboardManager actionStoryboard] instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
  }
  else {
    if (self.selectedViewController == selectedViewController) {
      [(UINavigationController *)self.selectedViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:animate]; // pop to root if tapped the same controller twice
    }
    [super setSelectedViewController:selectedViewController];
  }
}
```

I'm assuming you're programming with ARC enabled and that you have a class that manages your storyboards, but that's pretty straightforward anyway.

Comment: This should be the selected answer because it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: What's meant by this line in viewDidLoad: `[self.view _tabbarView];` - looks like a typo.

Comment: can you please convert this to swift code?

Answer (score 4):

**Below code works perfectly in my project.**

i have used **swift3** version as below :

i added MyTabBar.xib file which contains UIView with 4 buttons.
In xib file, Set Class of UIView. class = "MyTabBar"
Give 4 buttons Tag 1,2,3,4 accordingly..

and below myTabBarController file

myTabBarController.swift code as below :

```
class myTabBarController: UITabBarController {

var tabBarView: UIView!

var btn1: UIButton!
var btn2: UIButton!
var btn3: UIButton!
var btn4: UIButton!

var lastSender: UIButton!

var categoryViewController: CategoryViewController?
var subCategoryViewController: SubCategoryViewController?
var scoreViewController: ScoreViewController?
var profileViewController: ProfileViewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setup()

    tabBarView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyTabBar", owner: nil, options: nil)?.last as! UIView
    tabBarView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - tabBarView.frame.size.height, width: tabBarView.frame.size.width, height: tabBarView.frame.size.height)
    self.view.addSubview(tabBarView)

    btn1 = tabBarView.viewWithTag(1) as? UIButton
    btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.processBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn2 = tabBarView.viewWithTag(2) as? UIButton
    btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.processBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn3 = tabBarView.viewWithTag(3) as? UIButton
    btn3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.processBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn4 = tabBarView.viewWithTag(4) as? UIButton
    btn4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.processBtn), for: .touchUpInside)

    let width1 = self.view.frame.width/4
    btn1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width1, height: tabBarView.frame.size.height)
    btn2.frame = CGRect(x: btn1.frame.width, y: 0, width: width1, height: tabBarView.frame.size.height)
    btn3.frame = CGRect(x: btn2.frame.origin.x+btn2.frame.width, y: 0, width: width1, height: tabBarView.frame.size.height)
    btn4.frame = CGRect(x: btn3.frame.origin.x+btn3.frame.width, y: 0, width: width1, height: tabBarView.frame.size.height)

    lastSender = btn1
    selectedViewController = viewControllers?[0]
}

func processBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    lastSender = sender
    selectedViewController = viewControllers?[sender.tag - 1]

    if sender.tag == 1 {
        btn1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        btn2.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        btn3.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        btn4.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }else if sender.tag == 2 {
        btn1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        btn2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        btn3.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        btn4.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }else if sender.tag == 3 {
        btn1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        btn2.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        btn3.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        btn4.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }else if sender.tag == 4 {
        btn1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        btn2.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        btn3.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        btn4.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
}

func setup() {
    var viewControllers = [AnyObject]()

    categoryViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CategoryViewController") as? CategoryViewController
    viewControllers.append(categoryViewController!)

    subCategoryViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubCategoryViewController") as? SubCategoryViewController
    viewControllers.append(subCategoryViewController!)

    scoreViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScoreViewController") as? ScoreViewController
    viewControllers.append(scoreViewController!)

    profileViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as? ProfileViewController
    viewControllers.append(profileViewController!)

    self.viewControllers = viewControllers as? [UIViewController]
}

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    for view in tabBarView.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let btn = view as? UIButton {
            if btn == lastSender {
                btn.isSelected = true
            }
            else {
                btn.isSelected = false
            }
        }
    }

    if self.selectedViewController == viewController {
        (self.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController)?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        // pop to root if tapped the same controller twice
    }

    return (viewController != tabBarController.selectedViewController)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

This way you can design custom tabbar as per your need.

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask something related to your `custom tabBarController` code?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the step you need to follow in order to make the following view :-

1: Take a UITabBarController and set it as the rootViewController of your application window.

2: Now add Five Tab to this UITabbarController .

3: Add five seperate UINavigationController to each Tab individually.

4: Now add five different UIViewControllers to the UINavigationController respectively.

5: Create a Custom Tabbar now :

5.1 : One of the way of creating custom Tabbar is to take a UIView of Tabbar height and add UIButtons as Tab to the Tabbar.

6: Add the Custom tabBar on to the MainWindow . On choosing various button on your custom tabbar change the setSelectedIndex of your application UITabbarController.

Answer (score 0):

For ios 9.0+ 
use UIStackView in Horizontal direction and create a xib and named it 
CustomTabBarView

**CustomTabBarView.Xib**[image: insert uistackview in it]

[image: Set Stack view attributes like this]

Create Another View CustomTabBarItem.

**CustomTabBarItem.xib** 
[image]

create **CustomTabBarItem.swift** file for implement functionality of TabItem

```
class CustomTabItem: UIView {

//MARK:- IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var itemImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var itemTitle: SelectableLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var topButton: UIButton!

//MARK:- Variables
var isSelected: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        self.itemImage.image = CommonFunctions.getTabItemImage(isSelected: isSelected, tag: topButton.tag)
        itemTitle.isSelected = isSelected
        if isSelected {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.appDarkBlueColor
        }
        else {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.appWhiteColor
        }
    }
}

//MARK:- IBActions
@IBAction func onClickButton(_ sender: Any) {

}
```

}

In TabBarViewController Implement This Code

```
func createCustomTabBarView(tabItemCount: Int){

    customTabBarView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomTabBarView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.last as! UIView
    customTabBarView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - self.tabBar.frame.height, width: self.tabBar.frame.width, height: self.tabBar.frame.size.height)
    self.view.addSubview(customTabBarView)

    var stackView = UIStackView()
    for subView in customTabBarView.subviews{
        if subView is UIStackView {
            stackView = subView as! UIStackView
        }
    }

    for i in 0..<tabItemCount {
        let customTabItemView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomTabItem", owner: nil, options: nil)?.last as! CustomTabItem
        switch i {
        case CustomTabbarButtonTag.TabBarItem_First.rawValue:
            customTabItemView.itemTitle.text = "TabBarItem_First"
            customTabItemView.topButton.tag = CustomTabbarButtonTag.TabBarItem_First.rawValue
            customTabItemView.isSelected = false

        case CustomTabbarButtonTag.TabBarItem_Second.rawValue:
            customTabItemView.itemTitle.text = "TabBarItem_Second"
            customTabItemView.topButton.tag = CustomTabbarButtonTag.TabBarItem_Second.rawValue
            lastSelectedTabItem = customTabItemView
            customTabItemView.isSelected = true

        case CustomTabbarButtonTag.TabBarItem_Third.rawValue:
            customTabItemView.itemTitle.text = "TabBarItem_Third"
            customTabItemView.topButton.tag = CustomTabbarButtonTag.TabBarItem_Third.rawValue
            customTabItemView.isSelected = false

        case CustomTabbarButtonTag.TabBarItem_Fourth.rawValue:
            customTabItemView.itemTitle.text = "TabBarItem_Fourth" 
            customTabItemView.topButton.tag = CustomTabbarButtonTag.TabBarItem_Fourth.rawValue
            customTabItemView.isSelected = false
            cmsTabItem = customTabItemView

        default:
            break
        }

        customTabItemView.topButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tabBarButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(customTabItemView)
    }
}

//MARK:- IBActions
func tabBarButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton){
    // create global variable lastSelectedTabItem for store last selected tab item and set its isSelected value for manage highlight current selected tabItem
    lastSelectedTabItem.isSelected = false
    let customTabItem = sender.superview as! CustomTabItem
    lastSelectedTabItem = customTabItem
    lastSelectedTabItem.isSelected = true 
    self.selectedIndex = sender.tag
}
```